# adding weight to laravel cart with if statement

Tags: php, laravel, cart

I try to get my product weight to my cart and I can get it, but there is two issues:

1. Weight will add to my cart **only if** user add some attributes for
   product. `It has to be add no matter user select any attribute or not.`
2. Wight will add to each one of my attributes while it has to add
   separately as `third attribute`.

This is when user select other attributes

[image: screen1]

## Codes

here is my controller:

```
//finding product
      $product = Product::findOrFail($id);
      $weight = $product->weight;  //get wight of product

      // get product options in cart
      $customAttributes = [];
      if(!empty($request->attr)){
          foreach($request->attr as $sub) {

              // find the suboption
              $sub = Suboption::find($sub);
              if (!empty($sub->id)) {
                  array_push($customAttributes, [
                     'attr' => [
                        'name' => $sub->title,
                        'value' => $sub->price,
                        'weight' => $weight, // add weight to attributes
                      ]
                  ]);
              }
          }
      }

      //adding product and options to cart
      Cart::add(array(
        'id' => $product->id,
        'name' => $product->title,
        'price' => $product->price,
        'quantity' => $request->input('quantity'),
        'attributes' => $customAttributes, // attributes will add to cart in array
      ));
```

## UPDATE

After changing my data base on `bipin patel` answer and little changes I've got what i was looking for, but another issue came up.

And that was weight would come in product attribute list and I wasn't able to separate it `because I only need weight for shipment calculation` so **I decided to send my product `attributes` to `conditions` and get my weight as my `attribute`**.

In this case there is 2 benefits:

1. My product attributes price will add to cart automatically. (as condition)
2. I can get my weight anywhere I need without over loop. (as attribute)

`So here is my code now`

```
//finding product
      $product = Product::findOrFail($id);
      $weight = $product->weight;

      // get product options in cart
      $weightArray = [
        'attr' => [
              'name' => 'weight',
              'value' => $weight,
        ]
      ];
      $customAttributes = [];
      // array_push($customAttributes,$weightArray);
      if(!empty($request->attr)){
          foreach($request->attr as $sub) {
              // find the suboption
              $sub = Suboption::find($sub);
              if (!empty($sub->id)) {
                  array_push($customAttributes, [
                        'name' => $sub->title,
                        'value' => $sub->price,
                        'type' => 'additional',
                        'target' => 'item',
                  ]);
              }
          }
      }
      // dd($customAttributes);

      //adding product and options to cart
      Cart::add(array(
        'id' => $product->id,
        'name' => $product->title,
        'price' => $product->price,
        'quantity' => $request->input('quantity'),
        'attributes' => $weightArray,
        'conditions' => $customAttributes,
      ));
```

## Screenshots

`without choosing attributes`

[image: screen2]

`When I choose attributes`

[image: screen3]

`Here is dd of error above:`

[image: screen4]

Comment: right before loop add `$customAttributes = ['weight' => $weight];` and remove this line `'weight' => $weight,`

Comment: `"name" => "Black"` .... `"name" => "12 Inch"`.... uhhhh what are you shopping for there buddy?

Comment: @gunnar991 2 different attributes, size and color (your question is no help!)

Comment: Does the "Black" "12 inch".... something.... need A LOT of weight?

Comment: @gunnar991 no they just have price which in update i explained why i moved them to conditions to get their prices sum to product price.

Comment: That makes perfect sense, the "Blacker" and closer to "12 inches" you get makes the price start to really get up there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create weight array and push on customAttributes before start `if(!empty($request->attr))`

Like :

```
$weightArray = ['weight'=>$weight];
$customAttributes = [];
array_push($customAttributes,$weightArray); <--- push here
if(!empty($request->attr)){
...... rest of code
```

**UPDATE FOR CONDITION ADD**

```
if(!empty($request->attr)){
    foreach($request->attr as $sub) {
    // find the suboption
        $sub = Suboption::find($sub);
        if (!empty($sub->id)) {
            $itemCondition1 = new \Darryldecode\Cart\CartCondition(array(
                'name' => $sub->title,
                'type' => 'additional',
                'target' => 'item',
                'value' => $sub->price,
            ));
            array_push($customAttributes, $itemCondition1);
        }
    }
}
```

You do something like this for add conditions

Comment: thanks man, I updated my question would you mind take a look?

Comment: i think for condition you need to create condition like this **new \Darryldecode\Cart\CartCondition(array(**

Comment: GO to https://github.com/darryldecode/laravelshoppingcart and search "you may also add multiple conditions on an item" this you get example for add condition and also get  suggestion for  how to get conditions

Comment: but with all my if thing where should i place them in `new \Darryldecode\Cart\CartCondition(array(`

Comment: love the way you did it, only one issue: here is the result https://ibb.co/kbNWWS

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164873/discussion-between-bipin-patel-and-mafortis).